# Google Analytics set up report for users that go from page A to page B?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to create a report for users that go from page: "/publicar/" to page: "/publicacion/" (only head match).

I tried to set it up as a goal adding "/publicar/" as funnel but any visit to "/publicacion/" is taken as a goal so it's useless.

Is there a way to set it up as a goal? If not how do I create a report for users than go from page A to page B?

Answer (score 2):

If you set up the funnel so visiting the page /publicar/ is the first step in the funnel and make sure to mark the "required step" tickbox then this will only record goals for /publicacion/ of those people who have visited the first page